# Apply Read_more in Django cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I have using inherit plugin to inherit the content from one page to another. But Instead of the full page, I only want to show 10 lines on that placeholder and show "ReadMore", I have successfully placed the `Read More` redirecting to the full page. But I can't display only 10 lines content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

see [django truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatewords), if you still want to stick to lines, see how a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) can be added, you can extend the [Truncator class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py) to add support for lines, also see its usage at django [default filters code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py)

```
def _text_lines(self, length, truncate):
    """
    Truncates a string after a certain number of lines.
    """
    lines = self._wrapped.split('\n')
    if len(line) > length:
        lines = lines[:length]
        return self.add_truncation_text('\n'.join(lines), truncate)
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: Can't be done with `placeholder` tag of `django-cms`